# openssl - What is the public key default MD

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

In openssl.cnf **default_md** (use public key default MD) is set to **default**. How can I find out what the default is without generating a certificate? Is there a file I can check where it lists the default?

Answer (score 10):

`md` stands for `message digest` and from openssl version 1.1 the default digest is `sha256`.

> -md alg
>
> the message digest to use. Any digest supported by the OpenSSL dgst command can be used. This option also applies to CRLs.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ca.html

> The default digest was changed from MD5 to SHA256 in Openssl 1.1.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/dgst.html

Comment: I am using openssl 1.0.0m and generated a certificate:
    openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 360
When I check the certificate I see:
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
If the default is MD5 why is MD5 not listed when I look at the cert?

Comment: Just wanted to note,  Openssl 1.0.2j has sha256 as the default as well https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x4

Comment: This is misleading at best; the default hash used by the `dgst` command did change, but is completely separate from and has no effect on the default used by `req` and `ca` for certificates and similar. @Mr_Moneybags: not just j but all of 1.0.2

Comment: Also, 'manmaster' has been reorganized (I think in prep for 3.0) and your links now go to the generic 'openssl' page; you may want to use man1.1.1 instead, which at least for a while is still organized the older way (but not the really old 0.9 and 1.0 way, which I still have in older VMs)

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.0.0 (in 2010), the default hash used by `req` and `ca` -- or more exactly the default used by the internal functions those commands call, `X509_sign X509_REQ_sign X509_CRL_sign` -- is determined in `ASN1_item_sign` by calling `EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest_nid` which uses `pkey->ameth->pkey_ctrl(pkey,ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID,...)`. Thus in principle the hash choice could depend on the key type or even the actual key, but for the three public-key-signature types currently supported (RSA, DSA, ECDSA) it is in fact hardcoded: in 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 it is SHA1, and in 1.0.2 1.1.0 and 1.1.1 it is SHA256.

Before that, in 0.9.8, the default for `req` was hardcoded as SHA1, but for `ca` there was no default: if you didn't specify a hash on the commandline, and you didn't have `default_md` set to a valid hash, it failed. The upstream config, which might or might not be used in any particular case, had it set to sha1.